# Updating the state from an onclick event in a menuitem in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, onclick, action, reducers

I'm trying to update the view of the page everytime a new menuitem is clicked. I'm pulling these menuitems from a database and mapping over them and listing them in dropdown menus.

```
class AminoAcids extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
   this.props.fetchMicros();
  }

  renderData() {
   const { aminos } = this.props;
     return aminos.map((micro, index) => {
      return (
         <option onClick={() => 
        this.props.updateActiveResultView('aminoResults')} value={micro.value} 
       key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <option value="" selected>--Amino Acids--</option>
      {this.props.aminos && this.renderData()}
    </select>
    )
  }
```

The views I have are Intro, Amino, and Antioxidants, and right now it's set on Intro in my reducers, so I'm trying to get it to destroy the Intro and switch to Amino when one of the dropdown menuitems is clicked.

Reducers

```
const activeResultView = (state = 'Intro', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_RESULT_VIEW':
     return action.view;
      default:
     return state;
   }
};
```

Actions

```
export const updateActiveResultView = view => ({
  type: 'UPDATE_RESULT_VIEW',
  view,
});
```

I tried placing it on `<select>` but it threw me an error. Right now it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think there is no `onClick` event for `select`. What is happening when you try with `onChange`? It seems you set a handler for that but there is no `handleChange` in your code.

Comment: I guess the handleChange should do handleChange =() => {this.props.fetchMicros();}